# OpenShift Origin maven settings.xml

Tags: openshift-origin

I am using OpenShift with jboss as and jenkins, I want to go to build a custom settings.xml file but do not know how to do, any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Why not ask the support or forums on that site? And post back the answer here :)

Comment: Did you use the JBoss Application Server 7 Cartridge to create your project?

Comment: I have a nexus in local network that i use with mirror